# Are tefillin considered milchig or fleishig?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Exodus 13:9:

> וְהָיָה֩ לְךָ֨ לְא֜וֹת עַל־יָדְךָ֗ וּלְזִכָּרוֹן֙ בֵּ֣ין עֵינֶ֔יךָ
> לְמַ֗עַן תִּהְיֶ֛ה תּוֹרַ֥ת יְהוָ֖ה בְּפִ֑יךָ כִּ֚י בְּיָ֣ד חֲזָקָ֔ה
> הוֹצִֽאֲךָ֥ יְהֹוָ֖ה מִמִּצְרָֽיִם׃
>
> And it shall be for a sign unto thee upon thy hand, and for a memorial
> between thine eyes, **that the Torah of the LORD may be in thy
> mouth**; for with a strong hand hath the LORD brought thee out of
> Egypt.

The above says that by wearing tefillin, I am putting Torah in my mouth. Hmmm .. .usually, after I put on tefillin in the morning, I have a bagel with a shmeer or coffee with milk. I've been assuming all these years that tefillin was milchig.

But, perhaps, I've been wrong. Maybe tefillin are fleishig, and I should be waiting 6 hours to have my usual breakfast?

So what is tefillin - milchig or fleishig?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what you determine to be the Ikkarin and what the Tafillin.

If the Torah on the parchment is the Ikkarim, then the Torah is either an eitz chaim (parve) or a mayim (though I forget the citation), also parve.

If the Torah is the Tafillin, and the bayit and retzu'ot are the ikkarin, then they are leather and fleishig.

Comment: The Torah is also compared to Milk, so why aren't Tefillin Basar B'Chalav?